# Force emails from one server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have SharePoint 2010 Enterprise with 2 servers in the farm. One resides in our DMZ. Currently both servers issue email alerts. Can we make it so its only one of the server that always issues the alerts?

Answer (score 2):

Alerts are processed via Immediate Alerts timer job, if you force that timer job run only one server then it will fix it. One workaround i am thinking is this:

- Open Central Administration
- Under Application Management, under the databases section, click on
  the Manage content databases link
- For each database select it.
- At the bottom of the manage content database setting page select a
  preferred sever.
- Select the server from where you want to send the alerts.

Now draw back is, all timer jobs related to that DBs run on the same server.

http://chrisdomino.com/blog/post/the-truth-about-how-daily-sharepoint-alerts-actually-work

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify why you want this configuration, but I suspect that firewall or routing issues are the reason.

I would recommend using a single SMTP relay, and configure outgoing email to use that relay. The relay server can be placed in the appropriate network location and can be configured to only relay mail sent from the SharePoint servers (white-listed).

Comment: Firewall is configured to allow SMTP on Port 25 so its not causing us an issue but we are experiencing inconsistencies with alerts sending so to rule the secondary server (DMZ) out of the equation I'd like only one server setup to send alerts